# How would I go about finding the "new" depth of the water, so that I could subtract the cone's volume from it?

Tags: geometry, volume

A cylinder of radius 2 contains water to a depth ℎ. A cone with base radius  and perpendicular height  is lowered into the water. When the bottom of the cone is resting on the bottom of the beaker the water just covers the top of the cone. Find an expression for the initial depth of the water ℎ in terms of .

How could I find the new depth, so that I can define $h$ as $new depth - volume of cone$?

Comment: A useful result here is that circular cones take up one-third of the volume of their associated cylinder, so in the situation you describe you have one-third cone, two-thirds water. Can you work it out from there?

Comment: The new depth is $a$, the new volume of water is $4a^3*π$, and the volume of the cone $(πa^3)/3)$. Dividing   ℎ −    by the cross-sectional area of the cylinder ($4a^2π$) should give me the height, but the answer is incorrect. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof The radius of the cylinder is $2a$.

Answer (score 2):

The volume of water is $V_w=\pi(2a)^2 h$. The volume of the cone is $V_c=\frac13\pi (a)^2 a$.
To find the new height of the water $h^*$ use the equation:
$$
\pi(2a)^2 h^*=V_w+V_c\implies h^*=\frac{V_w+V_c}{\pi(2a)^2}=h+\frac1{12}a.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is the new depth not $a$, seeing as "when the bottom of the cone is resting on the bottom of the beaker the water just covers the top of the cone", and the cone's  perpendicular height is $a$.

Comment: Yes, it is. You correctly found the last step.